# How to choose headphones for best noise-cancelling?

Tags: headphones, noise-cancelling

I'm almost completely ignorant on the matter.

I have used since 2016 the [Plantronics BackBeat PRO](https://www.plantronics.com/za/en/support/manuals-guides/backbeat-pro) and I found the noise cancelling very good but it does not remove the noise of the train brakes when it arrives at the station, the same for the metro.

So I'm looking for a headset with better noise canceling that makes me feel comfortable with everything I want to hear (e.g. online course speech, music, etc).

I don't know how to properly search the headphone with such characteristics, because often is expressed with one of these forms:

- 31 (or other number) `db`
- `ANC`
- `SNR`
- noise-cancelling
- etc

Can you kindly suggest me how to find them?

Do you know of headphones like this that you have tried in critical conditions?

Someone know the noise-cancelling value for this headset?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> does not remove the noise of the train brakes when it arrives at the
>   station, the same for the metro.

Not even ear plugs with ear muffs over them will eliminate all sound. Train brakes are LOUD.

There is no absolute noise cancellation.

As far as finding the best noise canceling headphones you are just going to have to do lots of research, read data sheets, test reports, user reviews, go to the stores and try them out.

Take all of the info you find and make an informed decision.

Perhaps join a discussion forum to see what other have to say on the subject. Audio or stereo equipment forums ??

Perhaps research noise rejection, but that may interfere with some of the content you DO want to hear.

Comment: Suggest close as O/T